# ServiceStack v6 - Route starting with /api produces NotImplementedExceptio

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, servicestack

#### Greetings.

I started a new project with **ServiceStack v6**. I noticed that when I use routes starting with `/api`, they will produce a `NotImplementedException` when called. I believe this is due to the new API Explorer UI implemented on ServiceStack v6. I am not entirely sure about this but I have a hunch this might be the culprit.

Is there any way to disable API Explorer UI? I want my `/api` routes to work as they used to work on ServiceStack **5.13.2**
Or perhaps changing the `/api` prefix handler to something else would also be fine by me, API Explorer UI seems like a feature I would like to use.

#### Notes:

Removing `/api` from my route will make it work just fine. An interesting observation is that it will also work if I add another slash before `/api` and essentially call `http://localhost//api/chat/join`

**Working example:**

```cs
appHost.Routes.Add<JoinChatRequest>("/chat/join", ApplyTo.Get);
```

**Example producing a `NotImplementedException` when called:**

```cs
appHost.Routes.Add<JoinChatRequest>("/api/chat/join", ApplyTo.Get);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the [JSON /api pre-defined route](https://docs.servicestack.net/routing#json-api-pre-defined-route) that was [added in v6.0](https://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v6#new-api-route) which can be explicitly [can be disabled with](https://docs.servicestack.net/routing#disable-api-route):

```cs
ConfigurePlugin<PredefinedRoutesFeature>(feature => feature.JsonApiRoute = null);
```